# Installing vendor library using composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use the https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/ library to make graphql requests.

But for some reason it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.

I'm using this command to install:

```
composer require webonyx/graphql-php
```

Vendor folder with content + `composer.json` / `composer.lock` appear in the project folder.

When I try a simple code like:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphQL\Client;
use GraphQL\Query;


// Replace with your actual GraphQL endpoint and API key
$graphqlEndpoint = 'https://platformurl';

// Set up the GraphQL client
$client = new Client($graphqlEndpoint);

?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "GraphQL\Client" not found in
> /url/test.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /url/test.php on
> line 14

When I check composer.json it contains this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^15.7"
    }
}
```

I tried `composer install` or `update`.
I tried a `require` with the direct link to graphql folder.
But there is no difference.

I found that there was no src/client.php file in the graphql-php library folder, but I don't know if this is necessary or how that comes (chatGPT said this is the reason why it doesn't works)..

PHP Version is PHP 8+. What could be the reason?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what does that mean? If installing the package works, are oyu sure this problem is related to Composer after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, there is no `GraphQL\Client` (or `Query`) classes. Wherever you got the "simple code" from is not how the package is used. I suggest looking in the examples directory and other documentation in the repository to see how it can actually be used.

Answer (score 0):

If your useing autoload after adding new class you should run composer dump-autoload to cached list of classes

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have the php file in the `src` folder. Change the path to the `vendor` folder

```
- vendor
- src
-- client.php
```

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```